# Deleting rows in VBA based on a list

Tags: vba, excel, list, rows

I have two tabs in my spreadsheets (Report and Holidays). In column A of Holidays tab there is a list of dates (updated manually) which I want to exclude from Report tab (column E contains dates).

I have found a code which does what is needed but takes some time when the number of rows is around 100-200k:

```
Sub Holidays()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim d As Object, e, rws&, cls&, i&, j&
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each e In Sheets("Holidays").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    d(e.Value) = 1
Next e
Sheets("Report").Activate
rws = Cells.Find("*", After:=[a1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
cls = Cells.Find("*", After:=[a1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
For i = rws To 1 Step -1
    For j = 1 To cls
        If d(Range("A1").Resize(rws, cls)(i, j).Value) = 1 Then _
            Cells.Rows(i).Delete: Exit For
Next j, i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Is there a way to speed up that macro? Ideally it should take only several seconds to run.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Look at array solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379087/for-loop-using-dates-compile-error-syntax-error/50379235#50379235

Comment: Is this `Next j, i` and `Then _ Cells.Rows(i).Delete: Exit For` really working as you wish?

Comment: Yes it is working. I checked the results with the reports prepared manually, without a macro.

Comment: I see. Still, it hurts my eyes a bit, but if you like it - it is ok. Concerning the speeding up - put all the relevant rows in one range with a `Union()` and delete the range once. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50372692/5448626) or [even better here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350507/5448626)

Comment: I would rather use VLOOKUP in helper column, filter the helper column for non blank cells and delete the rows at once. All these can be coded in macro.

Comment: Thank you for all suggestions, currently I am using the method with deleting all of them at the end by help of Union(), which got be faster results but still takes around 3 minutes to be done.

Comment: What are the addresses of both ranges?

Comment: @JohnyL: I'm not sure If I know what you mean. In the report tab, there is data from column A to L. the dates are in column E. As for holidays, I have them listed in column A.

Answer (score 1):

This should remove about 10 K rows out of 200 K, in less than 30 seconds

Code bellow assumes that `UsedRange` on both sheets starts in `A1`, and

- Sheet `Holidays` contains only column `A` (in contiguous rows)
- Sheet `Report` contains dates to be removed in column `E` (in contiguous rows)
- Dates on both sheets are formatted as **`"m/d/yyyy"`**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemoveHolidaysFromReportFilterUnion()
    Const WS_NAME = "Report"
    Dim wsH As Worksheet:   Set wsH = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Holidays")
    Dim wsR As Worksheet:   Set wsR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WS_NAME)

    Dim del As Range, wsNew As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set del = GetRowsToDelete(wsH, wsR)
    If del.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        del.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=wsR)
        wsR.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
        With wsNew.Cells(1)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            .Select
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wsR.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        wsNew.Name = WS_NAME
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function GetRowsToDelete(ByRef wsH As Worksheet, ByRef wsR As Worksheet) As Range
    Const HOLIDAYS_COL = "A"
    Const REPORT_COL = "E"
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, itm As Variant

    ReDim arr(1 To wsH.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)
    i = 1
    For Each itm In wsH.UsedRange.Columns(HOLIDAYS_COL).Offset(1).Cells
        If Len(itm) > 0 Then
            arr(i) = itm.Text   'Create AutoFilter Array (dates as strings)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim ur As Range, del As Range, lr As Long, fc As Range

    With wsR.UsedRange
        Set ur = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1)
        Set del = wsR.Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, REPORT_COL)
    End With

    lr = wsR.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set fc = wsR.Range(wsR.Cells(1, REPORT_COL), wsR.Cells(lr, REPORT_COL))
    fc.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    If fc.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Set del = Union(del, ur.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    End If
    fc.AutoFilter
    Set GetRowsToDelete = del
End Function
```

---

Performance - `Removed about 5K rows out of a total of 100K`

```
Sheet Report   - Rows: 100,011, Cols: 11   (Rows Left: 94,805 - Deleted: 5,206)
Sheet Holidays - Rows:      20, Cols:  1

Initial Sub - Holidays()              - Time: 112.625 sec
RemoveHolidaysFromReportFilterUnion() - Time:  10.512 sec
```

---

Test Data

**`Holidays`**

[image: Holidays]

---

**`Report`** - **`Before`**

[image: ReportBefore]

**`Report`** - **`After`**

[image: ReportAfter]

Comment: Hello, I've tried your code but there is a problem with line:  
      `Set vis = ur.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` It says that no cells were found.

Comment: Thank you for that code! Unfortunately it seems to work only with cells containing a letter. It doesn't recognize dates (which are a criteria here) and therefore nothing is removed.

Comment: Can you provide 3 sample dates (exact format) from `Holidays` and 3 more from `Report` so I can test the code?

Comment: Sure, for instance I have those in Report:                                                   7/26/2016
    8/2/2016
    8/9/2016
    6/5/2017
and these in Holidays:5/25/2017
6/5/2017
6/23/2017

Comment: Great! How many total dates do you have in `Holidays`? All dates are in `Holidays.colA`, correct? And are all dates in `Report.colA` as well?

Comment: I have 14 dates in Holidays. Yes, they are in column A, starting A2.There are around 82k dates in Report, column E.

Comment: That works great! Thanks a lot for the help, Paul Bica!

Answer (score 0):

### I would suggest using arrays.

1. Populate an Array for the list of dates. example:

   arr = Array("Alpha","Bravo","Charlie")
2. Filter the report based on Criteria.

`Sheet17.Range("E1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=arr,` `Operator:=xlFilterValues`

3. Once the sheet is filtered, create a range of selected visible cells

`set myrange = range("A1:F" &_`

```
Cells(Rows.Count,"A").end(xlup).row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

4. Delele the Range using `Range(“YourRange”).EntireRow.Delete`

This will delete the range in 4 operations instead of looping through every row in the range based on the condition.

Hope that helps!